# Два различных значения слова "обельный"

Tags: этимология

Два противоположных значения слова *обельный* :
обельный холоп - полный, в крепостной зависимости, бессрочный (упоминание в Русской Правде);
обельный крестьянин - освобожденный от всех податей и повинностей.
В чем причина такого расхождения смыслов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А. ОБЕЛЬНЫЙ ХОЛОП - круглый, от от др.-русск. облый - "круглый".Есть две версии происхождения слова  "облый": 1)от "огибать, обволакивать"; 2) от "обвальный, вал, волна, валить, катить".

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/62429/ХОЛОПЫ
ХОЛО́ПЫ, категория зависимого населения на Руси 10 — начала 18 веков, по правовому положению близкая к рабам. Господин мог неограниченно распоряжаться личностью холопа: убить, продать, отдать за долги. Холопами становились в результате пленения, самопродажи, продажи за долги или преступления, женитьбы на холопке.До конца 15 века на Руси существовало ТОЛЬКО ОБЕЛЬНОЕ ХОЛОПСТВО, или ПОЛНОЕ, как оно стало называться позднее. На протяжении 16 века роль холопов в барщинном хозяйстве УМЕНЬШАЕТСЯ за счет вовлечения в него крепостных крестьян. С конца 16 века наиболее распространенным становится ДВОРОВОЕ ХОЛОПСТВО. С 17 века Положение посаженных на землю холопов СБЛИЖАЕТСЯ с крепостными крестьянами. В 1722—1724 годах все холопы, в том числе и дворовые, были обложены подушной податью, став частью массы КРЕПОСТНЫХ КРЕСТЬЯН.

Б. ОБЕЛЬНЫЕ ЛЮДИ - освобожденные от податей.
http://www.diletant.ru/blogs/40520/7043/
Потомки людей, оказавших услуги царскому дому и получивших за услугу награду назывались на Руси обельными людьми. Или ОБЕЛЕННЫМИ людьми. Были чёрные (чернь) стали побелей – обельные. Дело на Руси обычное.

Пример.

Потомки священника Ермолая Герасимова, который во время заточения царицы инокини Марфы в Егорьевском погосте «твердо и непоколебимо» служил ей, в награду за что и получил в 1614 г. от Михаила Федоровича жалованную грамоту на владение  дворцовой волостью, с освобождением от платежа дани денежной, хлебной и ямской, от требования посоха и ямщика, от участия во всех разметах и вообще от всех пошлин.

Answer (score 3):

Есть  глагол-обломать и  оттуда? облом. Существительное- лом?
Обло--относится к форме, которую можно получить действием и инструментом.
От возгласов оп,ап, хоп, об,хлоп, ,еть,ОП ЛЯ --Дальше естественный мат.Матерный говор--родная речь по-сербски. Теперь это междометия или приставки.

Ломъ-палка, а раньше была буква ЯТЬ. ТВЕРДАЯ ТАКАЯ.
 НО ТАБУ. Изъяли. Мешала. Вопрос кому?

не позднее Облатка. та облатка -таблетка. КРУГЛАЯ!
 (от латин. oblata - приношения) ?????!!!!!
Впечатляет наглость западная и прозападная, заподлянка. Это русское слова "плата", позаимствовано в Европе, которая так и не смогла ничего проще придумать, как возвести это к листку еврейскому. Печатные деньги появились недавно, даже дата известна, 1690 г.
Отдельный  разговор.  У нас корней,  связей-отношений  больше, смысл перетекает не останавливаясь !!! У нас язык-дерево, а у них одни ветки.

Латынь-сборная солянка.  И прав Фоменко. ВСЕ не ТАК.
Разбирать по отдельности не получится, получится как у Фасмеров, плохая каша, с претензией на исключительность от придуманной на западе ИЕ.

Облако - око, облачение, обель-ить-белый, облатка --слов навалом идет.
А есть-Обложить, вроде другой корень. Ложь, ложИть, лежать. лгут и ложь--это измена, в постели, где лежат. ОПЯТЬ ТАБУ?

а облый-наиболее логично с точки зрения слововобразования, если круглый.
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/285534

короче--обельный холоп, и обельный люд по смыслу разные, но получились от одного источника.

Все путЁм, ребята, Прорвемся.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое дополнение к ответу Софии.
В словаре 1847 есть оба слова "обельный", но на разных страницах.
*Обелъ* - крепостной холоп, *обельный* - обращенный в рабство, крепостной.
*Обѣлъ* - освобождение от повинностей, *обѣльный* - свободный от податей крестьянин; *обѣльная грамота*.
Послереформенное (1918) правописание, без **буквы ѣ**, затруднило различение одинаково звучащих терминов, которые произошли от неродственных корней.
Кажется, это второй простейший пример  (после *мир - мiр*) былой важности "лишних букв" русского алфавита.